# Redirect to new page with ActionResult from ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, actionlink, actionresult

I have tried a number of ways yet had no luck...I must be way off here.

Here is my action link:

```
                        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete all", "Empty",
                    new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        OnBegin = String.Format("if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete {0} items?')){{return false;}}",ViewBag.TotalItems),
                        OnComplete = "location.reload()",
                    }
```

and my ActionResult, I have tried all commented out returns:

```
   public ActionResult Empty()
    {

        //return Json(new
        //{
        //    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
        //    isRedirect = true
        //});

        //return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

        //return Redirect("http://google.ca");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        //return new JsonResult() { Data = new { redirectURL = "/" } };
    }
```

Yet I can never get it to redirect to any new page :/

Any help or direction is appreciated...

EDIT: I should note that I didn't originally use the "OnComplete" line until recently after trying everything.

Comment: Are you even hitting the controller? It's not your controller which is the issue as that will redirect no matter what happens, so the issue is with the `Ajax.ActionLink`. Also what is the reasoning for using Ajax.ActionLink, you are just handling a normal ActionResult so why not just use Html.Action and use JQUERY to handle the yes/no response.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely hitting the controller, I've put break points in etc.

Comment: Works for me(MVC5). Why it is POST request? Have you another "Empty" action in this controler? Have you "Home" controler?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine, are you sure you're just not calling it from the Home Index view and it looks like you aren't changing page? The POST will be for the purpose of deleting the user as the ActionLink seems to indicate a DB call.

Comment: Changing it to a Html ActionLink worked and serves my purpose...Thank Damian.

Comment: No problem, do you want me to post some kind of answer so it can be seen for others in the future?

Answer (score 1):

One crude way of doing accomplishing what you need is this:

in the Empty function, replace `RedirectToAction` to:

```
var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home");
return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
```

In your javascript, replace

```
OnComplete = "location.reload()",   <-- this additional comma should be removed
```

to

```
OnSuccess= "OnAjaxSuccess"
```

then add a function in Javascript

```
function OnAjaxSuccess(data) {
    window.location.href = data.Url;
}
```

Comment: In the Javascript function, it should be ```window.location.href = data.Url;```

Answer (score 0):

You get the response, but you didn't get it as you expected.
You make an async call to server and your **response** is in **result** parameter of **OnSuccess** function.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete all", "Empty",
  new AjaxOptions()
  {
      HttpMethod = "POST",
      OnBegin = String.Format("if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete {0} items?')){{return false;}}",ViewBag.TotalItems),
      OnComplete = "location.reload()",
      OnSuccess = "Success"
  }
```

And you result  is here, in **data** parameter

```
<script>
    function Success(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
</script>
```

**data** parameter contains page returned by **Index** action

You can try to use HtmlHelper instead of AjaxHelper